# JOINTJS : Self referencing a shape in a link

Tags: jointjs

I would like to self-reference a shape in a link. Basically the source and the target of the link are the same.

It is working but the link is hidden by the shape:
https://imageshack.com/i/f2mu7jp

Here is what I would like to do:
https://imageshack.com/i/mujp9lp

I know that I can use "vertices" in the definition of a link but I don't know the XY position of the start and the end point

```
var connect = function(source, sourcePort, target, targetPort) {
    var link = new joint.shapes.devs.Link({
        source: { id: source.id, selector: source.getPortSelector(sourcePort) },
        target: { id: target.id, selector: target.getPortSelector(targetPort) }
    });
    if(source == target){
        console.log(link);
        console.log(source);
    }

    graph.addCell(link);
};
```

How can I get the position of the start and the end point ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is not in the official API but there is a `getConnectionPoint()` method on link views. By knowing the connection points, you can compute the 2 vertices needed for the self-link:

... after graph.addCell(link)... - at this point the link view is created in the paper...

```
var linkView = paper.findViewByModel(link);
var sourcePoint = linkView.getConnectionPoint(
    'source', 
    link.get('source'),
    _.first(link.get('vertices')) || link.get('target'));
var targetPoint = linkView.getConnectionPoint(
    'target',
    link.get('target'),
    _.last(link.get('vertices')) || sourcePoint);
```

... now you can compute the 2 other vertices (for orthogonal self-link) and do:

```
link.set('vertices', myTwoVertexArray);
```

The signature of the getConnectionPoint() method is:

```
getConnectionPoint(end, sourceOrTargetOrPoint, referenceSourceOrTargetOrPoint);
```

Where `end` is either `'source'` or `'target'`, `sourceOrTargetOrPoint` is either `link.get('source')` or `link.get('target')` and `referenceSourceOrTargetOrPoint` is the reference point needed to compute the "sticky" point (usually the other side of the link or the closest vertex).